# Is there any way to relate between tables in a DataSet

Tags: c#

I have a `DataSet` with 3 tables `Categories`, `Items` and `Products`. I can access them individually. But I want to bind them in 3 different `ComboBoxes` such that, changing Categories reflects Items and changing Items reflects Products. I guess this might be done creating relations between tables. Please help me on this.

Comment: visit this it might help you http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2012/07/cascading-combobox-in-winforms-windows-forms.html

Comment: @Satpal Ick code! Also note that those "relations" are all implicit and manual. (As opposed to LINQ2SQL/EF which makes such relations explicit.)

Comment: thanks @Satpal. I am looking into this.

Comment: @user2246674:  You can make the relations explicit with ADO.NET `DataSet.Relations` too.

Comment: @J0e3gan That's more interesting; have a link/answer?

Comment: Yeah, I can make cascading ComboBoxes. But I want to do this using DataSet relations. Any useful link, please? @J0e3gan

Comment: @user2246674 (and OP):  Yeah, I added an answer with an example and a link.  TMTOWTDI with ADO.NET data sets in this respect; and it has been a while since I have used data sets with data relations; but hopefully I answered sufficiently for the wait. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *bunches* of ways to skin this cat with ADO.NET data sets, but you can make the relations between the data tables with `DataSet.Relations`.  Check out [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82dfwh2t.aspx) for more info.

Here is an example with the relations you outlined and only taking it far enough down one possible path to give you the idea:

```
var ds = new DataSet();

// Add the Categories table with a CategoryID column, and add a few rows to it.
var categories = ds.Tables.Add("Categories");
var categoryIDColumn = categories.Columns.Add("CategoryID", typeof(int));
categories.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1 });
categories.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2 });
categories.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3 });

// Add the Items table with ItemID & CategoryID (FK) columns, and add a few Categories-relatable rows to it.
var items = ds.Tables.Add("Items");
var itemIDColumn = items.Columns.Add("ItemID", typeof(int));
var itemCategoryIDColumn = items.Columns.Add("CategoryID", typeof(int));
items.Rows.Add(new object[] { 11, 1 });
items.Rows.Add(new object[] { 12, 2 });
items.Rows.Add(new object[] { 13, 3 });

// Add the Products table with ProductID & ItemID (FK) columns, and add a few Items-relatable rows to it.
var products = ds.Tables.Add("Products");
var productIDColumn = products.Columns.Add("ProductID", typeof(int));
var productItemIDColumn = products.Columns.Add("ItemID", typeof(int));
products.Rows.Add(new object[] { 21, 11 });
products.Rows.Add(new object[] { 22, 12 });
products.Rows.Add(new object[] { 23, 13 });

// Add the FK relationships (or data relations as it were).
var categoryItemsRelation = ds.Relations.Add("FK_CategoryItems", categoryIDColumn, itemCategoryIDColumn);
var itemProductsRelation = ds.Relations.Add("FK_ItemProducts", itemIDColumn, productItemIDColumn);

// Run through an example of a selected ID in the categories dropdown.
int selectedCategoryID = 1;
var selectedCategory = categories.Select(String.Format("CategoryID = {0}", selectedCategoryID))[0];
var filteredItems = selectedCategory.GetChildRows(categoryItemsRelation);

Console.WriteLine("selectedCategoryID == {0}", selectedCategoryID);
Console.WriteLine("selectedCategory[categoryIDColumn] == {0}", selectedCategory[categoryIDColumn]);
foreach (var childItem in filteredItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine("filteredItems includes:");
    Console.WriteLine(
            "\t{0} : {1}, {2} : {3}",
            itemIDColumn.ColumnName,
            childItem[itemIDColumn],
            itemCategoryIDColumn.ColumnName,
            childItem[itemCategoryIDColumn]);
}

// ...and so forth.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by Dataset.Relation refer this and try to implement in your code

```
// Define the relationship between Categories and Products.
DataRelation relat = new DataRelation("CatProds",
ds.Tables["Categories"].Columns["CategoryID"],
ds.Tables["Products"].Columns["CategoryID"]);


// Add the relationship to the DataSet.
ds.Relations.Add(relat);
```